# variations of the canonical form of a second order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, transformation, change-of-variable, canonical-transformation

Is it true to say that for each PDE of second order, there is one single canonical form? (or at least to the extant of multiplication by a constant/function of the original variables).

So far it it appears to be quite true, based on the basic examples I've tried, but I'm hardly confidant about it.

Is it true at all? Is it true under certain conditions? (maybe only true per variable change but not necessarily for different transformations?)

If this is true, I'd very much appreciate a source for such a statement/proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know. Why is it interesting? Will it help you build something particularly cool if it is true?

Comment: @mathreadler unfortunately no. It will however, help me with my HW assignment. We were given a PDE that behaves differently in each quadrant, and while it is asymmetrical,  I'm trying to show that the canonical form in quadrants 1,3 is the same and so for 2,4.

Comment: What about $|u_x|=1$, $u_x^2 = 1$, $\log(u_x^2)=0$, etc. Which one is canonical?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I might be missing something. I was referring to second order PDE's, and I'm not sure how those examples are that, nor how are any of them canonical (form of $Aw_{ss}+Bw_{st}+Cw_{tt}+l.o.t=0$).

Comment: Second order PDEs include 1st order as a special case. If you are particular about it, then replace $u_x$ by $u_{xx}$ in the examples to get second order PDEs. I think you mean second order *linear* PDEs.